# Dynamic \headheight based on natural height of header?

Tags: spacing, header-footer

Is it possible to dynamically set the current page's `\headheight` to match the natural height of the current page's header?  Or simulate it by inserting `\vspace`?

For example, the following document inserts a rule with random height (between 10 and 60 points) into each page's header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[
  papersize={5in,2.5in},
  margin=0in,
  includehead,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[first=10, last=60]{lcg}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\hdr}{\rand\rule{1pt}{\therand\p@} The rule is
  \arabic{rand} points high}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{\hdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}%
\lipsum%
\end{document}
```

With this document you'll notice that the header usually runs into the text.  I'd like the text on each page to always start `\headsep` below the header baseline, no matter how tall the header is on that page.

(Using a random number might not be the best way to illustrate this problem, as I'm not sure what happens if the document is subject to multiple passes.  But hopefully my point gets across.)

Comment: As far as I understand it, the header/footer is added to the page after it has been set. So, at the point of constructing the page text body, there is no reference to the height of the header (or footer). Does your head height on a specific page change every time, or is it fixed for that page?

Comment: It is tricky to in general, I think.  But there is a [FAQ entry](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=chngmargonfly) (but it doesn't solve your problem); see in general the section on page layout.

Comment: @Werner:  The header height is fixed for that page, but it may differ between pages (e.g., the header height on page 1 may be 12pt, on page 2 it may be 15pt, etc.).

Comment: @Werner:  What if I knew a page's header contents before the is filled in?  E.g., I know that the header for page 1 is `\headerforpageone`, the header for page 2 is `\headerforpagetwo`, etc.  Does that make this problem easier/possible to solve?

Comment: @Werner:  Also, what about doing multiple passes?  E.g., on the first pass guess the height, then when the header is added write out the actual height so that the second pass can use the actual height?

Comment: Heiko has already given an answer to a similar question, IIRC. But I am unable to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your MWE is setup makes the problem much harder. The issue is

```
\newrobustcmd*{\hdr}{\rand\rule{1pt}{\therand\p@} The rule is \arabic{rand} points high}
```

means you do not know the height of the header until the header is being typeset. The problem is that if you do not know the height of the header until after the page is typeset, you end up in a loop since in order to typeset a page you need the text height, which requires knowing the header height, which of course you do not know until after the page has been typeset. From the comments it doesn't sound like this is a critical part of the question. A slight redefinition of `\hdr` makes the problem much easier

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\hdr}{\rule{1pt}{\therand\p@} The rule is
  \arabic{rand} points high (\the\paperheight, \the\headsep, \the\headheight, \the\textheight)\rand}
\rand
```

In this way we know the height of the header before the header is typeset and we set a random length for the next header. The problem then becomes changing the `\headheight` and `\textheight` after every page. You probably can use the [`everyshi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) package, but I went with the [`afterpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package. Adding the following to your MWE gives the desired results

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\hdr}{\rule{1pt}{\therand\p@} The rule is
  \arabic{rand} points high (\the\paperheight, \the\headsep, \the\headheight, \the\textheight)\rand}
\rand
\newcommand{\myafter}{%
  \afterpage{%
    \global\headheight=\therand\p@\relax%
    \global\textheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\headheight-\headsep\relax%
    \myafter%
  }%
}
\headheight=\therand\p@\relax%
\textheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\headheight-\headsep\relax%
\myafter
\makeatother
```

The full MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[
  papersize={5in,2.5in},
  margin=0in,
  includehead,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[first=10, last=60]{lcg}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\hdr}{\rand\rule{1pt}{\therand\p@} The rule is
  \arabic{rand} points high}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{\hdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{afterpage}
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\hdr}{\rule{1pt}{\therand\p@} The rule is
  \arabic{rand} points high (\the\paperheight, \the\headsep, \the\headheight, \the\textheight)\rand}
\rand
\newcommand{\myafter}{%
  \afterpage{%
    \global\headheight=\therand\p@\relax%
    \global\textheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\headheight-\headsep\relax%
    \myafter%
  }%
}
\headheight=\therand\p@\relax%
\textheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\headheight-\headsep\relax%
\myafter
\makeatother


\begin{document}%
\lipsum%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!  I couldn't get your code to work -- can you please provide a complete MWE?

Comment: @RichardHansen I edited the answer to include the full MWE.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE.  The randomness doesn't seem to be working in your MWE -- `\therand` is the same on the second and subsequent pages.  Perhaps this is a bug in `lcg` and is unrelated to your answer?

Comment: It's a bug in `lcg` v1.2, fixed in v1.3.